# Rails Asset Pipeline URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, the asset pipeline concats all your assets (images, css, js and fonts) and loads them from an assets folder.

First question... where does this assets folder that the files are loaded from **compressed** exist? I was under the impression it was `public/assets/` But when running the app I can't seem theme in that folder...

Secondly, after compression the files are loaded directly from the assets folder at the same level... so images are with css and js, etc. Is it possible to change this so that the subfolders are kept intact?

So turn

`/assets/logo-ffbd470b80efb31e6e852d938c4e3db30fda9dfd1b6f07a0ed36449f1ac9febc.png`

to

`/assets/images/header/logo-ffbd470b80efb31e6e852d938c4e3db30fda9dfd1b6f07a0ed36449f1ac9febc.png`